# How to access Woocommerce API with Flutter?

Tags: php, android, wordpress, woocommerce, flutter

Woocommerce API implements Oauth1 with consumer key/secret.

Here is my code to access WordPress API with Flutter

```
Future<String> getData() async {

var response = await http.get(
    Uri.encodeFull( "http://jalania.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts" ),
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
this.setState(() {
  data = JSON.decode(response.body);
});
}
```

I've changed the API url to Woocommerce API, *http://jalania.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products* and got empty responses.

Does anyone know how to access Woocommerce API with flutter?

Comment: The official package is out now. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/woocommerce_api

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna use this: https://github.com/lakexyde/dart-woocommerce-api. Though still needs some cleaning but it does work.

```
Map<String,dynamic> params = {
  "url": 'https://example.com',
  "consumerKey": "ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "consumerSecret": "cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "wpAPI": true,
  "version": 'wc/v2'
}
```

And then:

```
WooCommerceAPI wooAPI = new WooCommerceAPI(params);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add the authorization to WooCommerce API. I do not know how to add the authorization parameter in Flutter. But you need to add something like below code.

```
Future<String> getData() async {

var response = await http.get(
    Uri.encodeFull( "http://jalania.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts" ),
    authorization:{"consumer_key": "XXXXXXXX1212","consumer_secret":"XXXXX1212"},
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
this.setState(() {
  data = JSON.decode(response.body);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Widget> products = [];

Future getProducts() async {

    /// Initialize the API
    WooCommerceAPI wc_api = new WooCommerceAPI(
        "https://www.yourwebsite.com",
        "ck_your_consumer_key",
        "cs_your_consumer_secret"
    );

    /// Get data using the endpoint
    var p = await wc_api.getAsync("products");
    return p;
}
```

It can help you: https://pub.dev/packages/woocommerce_api#-installing-tab-

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using: https://pub.dev/packages/woosignal

It returns the object models too, here's some documentation - https://woosignal.com/docs/api/1.0/installing-flutter-sdk

`Packages get`

```
dependencies:
  woosignal: ^1.0.2
```

```
// CONFIG FOR WOOSIGNAL
var wsConfig = {
"appKey":"your app key",
"debugMode":true
};

// CREATING AN INSTANCE
WooSignal.getInstance(config: wsConfig).then( (wcStore) {

    wcStore.getProducts().then( (products) {
        print(products[0].name);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would want a complete plug and play Woocommerce Sdk that handles authentication, products, customer, shipping etc for you, you can use the Woo Commerce SDK library for flutter at https://pub.dev/packages/woocommerce

```
Woocommerce myWoocommerce = WooCommerce(baseUrl: yourBaseUrl, consumerKey: yourConsumerKey, consumerSecret: consumerSecret);
```

Then simply register your new customer.

```
WooCustomer newCustomer = WooCustomer(id: id, firstName:firstName, etc);
myWoocommerce.createCustomer(newCustomer); //Returns the created Woocommerce customer.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying with flutter wooCommerce api document https://pub.dev/packages/woocommerce_api#-readme-tab-

But it was not working in my case, there has consumerKey & consumerSecret with url. In Postman it return the value
but not in Flutter code. Below steps are working in my project

```
Future<dynamic> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get("URL",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "AuthorizationToken"},
    ).catchError(
          (error) {
        return false;
      },
    );

    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Where 'Authorization' you can get using Postman. After hit the url with consumerKey & consumerSecret, Postman generate AuthorizationToken, then you can use AuthorizationTokenin that way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution if you need custom data:

First I installed package https://pub.dev/packages/woocommerce, but their api `woocommerce.getProducts()` didn't give the informations I needed (custom data inside acf), so I did the following:

1. I made a fork of the github project :https://github.com/RayOkaah/woocommerce
2. I cloned the forked project using terminal `git clone [FORKED PROJECT URL]` (example `git clone https://github.com/MireilleKhalifeh/woocommerce.git`)
3. I made my changes inside the file products.dart (located inside /wocommerce/lib/models/): I created Acf class, then add an Acf variable to WooProduct class like the rest of variables.
4. Pushed my changes.
5. In my flutter project, in `pubspec.yaml` I added under dependencies:

   ```
   dependencies:

     woocommerce:
       git: [FORKED PROJECT URL] #for example https://github.com/MireilleKhalifeh/woocommerce.git
   ```

Now I can access the data inside Acf class from their Product class.

```
Future getProducts() async {
  WooCommerce woocommerce = WooCommerce(
    baseUrl: '[url]',
    consumerKey: '[consumerKey]',
    consumerSecret: '[consumerSecret]',
    isDebug: false);
  Machine.products = await woocommerce.getProducts();
  return Future.value(MyHomePage());
}
```

And I access it like this:

```
Machine.products[0].acf.model
```

I hope it hepls.